# Ignoring folder pattern in deja-dup

Tags: ubuntu, duplicity

In Ubuntu (disco), how do I tell deja-dup to ignore a folder pattern? I want for example to make it skip any folder, in any path, that is named node_modules.
When I try to add folders to the ignore list, it won't allow me to type something (like **/node_modules), only pick a folder from the file system.

Comment: need this for **/target/* folders produced by maven builds too

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, Déjà Dup doesn't support that. The problem has been discussed for more than a decade [¹](https://bugs.launchpad.net/deja-dup/+bug/374274) [²](https://gitlab.gnome.org/World/deja-dup/-/issues/112), yet it is stuck at zero progress because devs seem to expect a perfect UI design proposed to solve all use cases—even for beginner users which probably don't have this problem—from the get go, instead of just providing a simple glob pattern input method which will solve it for most users.

The best workaround in my opinion, although admittedly hacky, is [a solution by Ian Puleston](https://askubuntu.com/a/1310968/62141) delegating to a shell script the expansion of glob patterns at backup run time.